# Problem with Heroku and PHP

Tags: php, heroku

I'm creating a PHP application within Heroku. The problem is Heroku doesn't understand some tags as PHP. For example, `<?=$some_var?>` is not recognized as PHP, but as pure HTML.

Do I have to configure something or use `<?php echo $some_var ?>`, for example, instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These `<?=` opening tags are called "short opening tags", and their use is set the [PHP configuration file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php).

It is generally not advised to use short tags for this very reason; there's no guarantee the server you'll deploy on will be configured to use them.

Comment: FYI, PHP short tags are default and always starting with PHP 5.4. See http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php.

Answer (score 4):

You need to turn on short opening tags for your app on Heroku.  Create a file called "php.ini" in the root folder of your project and add the following to it:

```
short_open_tag = true
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this without suggesting a workaround! I needed to change a different configuration option – which has no workaround – and this solution did the trick :)